# Можно ли рассматривать в качестве зависимых слов придаточное предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот

У меня не выгугливаются ответы на:

*- деепричастие с придаточным предложением - это деепричастный оборот?*

*- если к деепричастию примыкает придаточное предложение, его можно считать "зависимыми словами"?*

*- если деепричастие имеет в качестве зависимых слов придаточное, то...*

В общем, я по-всякому вопрошала - без результата.

Требовалось объяснить необходимость запятой после деепричастия:

*Мальчик взял книгу и* (пусто-пусто) *обнаружив, что до конца еще далеко, погрузился в чтение.*

Как правильно обосновать необходимость запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мальчик взял книгу и, **обнаружив, что до конца еще далеко**, погрузился в чтение.

**Общий принцип современного правописания:** Деепричастия и деепричастные обороты в различных синтаксических конструкциях обособляются независимо от постановки других знаков препинания. Союзы могут относиться как к структуре данного предложения, так  соединять деепричастные обороты как однородные члены.

(1) Виталик оглянулся и, **убедившись, что мы тут одни**, подошел ближе. [Алексей Моторов. Преступление доктора Паровозова (2013)]

Сначала Никита поглядел за Максима и, **только убедившись, что никого и ничего больше за дверью нет**, снял цепочку. [Виктор Пелевин. Жизнь насекомых (1993)]

Постановка запятой соответствует только грамматическому принципу, так как пауза в этом случае не делается.

**Но вот в дореформенной орфографии в похожей конструкции запятой нет** (наверное, по принципу "нет паузы ― нет запятой"):

(2)...два молодых туземца **побрели** к поплавкам, несколько раз с опаской **трогали** их **и только убедившись**, что птица не подает признаков жизни, они осмелели и погнали поплавки к берегу лагуны. [В. А. Обручев. Коралловый остров (1947)]